# Getting points that overlap with polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have two geometries:

multi point **A**

multi polygon **B**

I want to get all the points of **A** that overlap with the polygon **B**

I am not sure how to run this query. I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(A.geom, B.geom)
FROM point AS A, poly AS B
```

But with little succes. How can I change it so that i get only the points of **A** that are overlap with **B**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `WHERE` clause so with the `ST_INTERSECTS` clause returns a boolean value if the Geometries/Geography spatially intersect in 2D, while ST_Intersection returns a geometry that represents the point set intersection of the geometries ([as per documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)).

so the query needs to be:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM point as A, poly AS B 
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(A.geom, B.geom)
```

for more insight have a look at the documentation of [ST_Intersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html)